# Chrome extensionのoptions.htmlで日本語が文字化けする

Tags: html, 文字化け, chrome-extension

`<meta http-equiv=”Content-Type” content=”text/html; charset=UTF-8″>`や`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Shift_JIS">`なども試してみましたがダメでした。
一応文字化けが起こる最小コードです。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Check Periodicall Options</title>
</head>
<body>
    今日
</body>
</html>
```

なおテキストエディタでファイルを開くと文字化けせず、文字コードはUTF-8と表示されます。

Comment: 補足: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/69366/754 からの続きの議題の様子です。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UTF-8 で記述したコードが、**ブラウザで別の文字コードと解釈された**ことによる問題だと思います。私の環境で当該コードを実行すると、 UTF-8 で記述したコードは Shift_JIS として解釈されていました。

この問題は [`meta` 要素の `charset` 属性](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta#attr-charset)を用いて**文字コードを宣言**することで解決出来ます。既に質問者さんも同様の方法を試されているようですが、それらの試行が機能しなかった原因は、質問文に書かれたコードから、以下のように推測出来ます。

1. ダブルクォーテーションが U+0022 ではなく U+201D になっている
2. 指定している文字コードが UTF-8 でない

最後に、文字化けの改善を確認したコードを以下に示します。

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Check Periodicall Options</title>
</head>
<body>
    今日
</body>
</html>
```